# iOS custom smart app banner

Tags: ios, smartbanner

I want to have custom view for smart app banner which I think is not possible. but I have seen it in wikipedia mobile site which is smaller than standard apple banner.

wikipedia shows custom banner on its mobile site only if wikipedia app is installed. if it is not installed or user uninstalls it then banner disappears.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of banners?

Comment: u want add banner?

Comment: No i have added the banner, but I want to customise it like wikipedia

Comment: try lcbannerview demo in github

Comment: the library u suggested is to be implemented on app. but i want to have it on my website

Comment: u want to implement banner in your website?

Comment: yes apple's smart app banner appears on website only

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about 'Open in app' banner? Those comes by default if you have supported for [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in the app.

See screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

For iOS6+, you can use Smart Banners: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

One of your requirement is to not show when the app is not installed (instead of promoting the app).
I do not know of a way to test for installation but I would look

- url scheme: seems limited because the app will always open instead of
  just being able to check if system can answer
- cookies: can a cookie
  be set from inside app that would be reused by safari when visiting
  the same domain?
- files: create a file from the app and try to open it
  from safari

Comment: Wikipedia mobile site doesn't show banner as soon as I uninstalled the wikipedia app. I am just curious how they do it.

Comment: cookies or files would not necessarily disappear on app uninstall